# Binary quadratic form which takes values that are rational time a square

Tags: nt.number-theory, number-fields

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a totally real number field, $a$ an element of $\mathbb{K}$. Consider the quadratic form $q(X,Y) = X^2-aY^2$ and assume that for every number $c$ represented by $q$, if $c$ has the same sign at every real place of $\mathbb{K}$ then $c$ can be written as $q k^2$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $k \in \mathbb{K}$.

How can I prove that $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Why are you interested in knowing the answer to this question? What's the motivation?

Comment: Just a necessary condition I came across which seemed easy at first, but turned out not to be (at least for me).